# Stop function from returning variable with same data type

Tags: vb.net, function, dataset

I am calling a function that returns a data set. However, to generate the data set I have to grab a parameter from another table, which necessitates another data set being created in the function to retrieve that parameter. The issue is that once the first data set is created to get the parameter for the second data set, the function is returning to the calling code, rather than running to the return statement. Is there a way around this?

Example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim dataset as new dataset
  dataset = GetList(PathToDB, AccessCode)

End Sub

Function GetList(Path as String, AccessCode as String)

  Dim ListConnectionString as String = "..."
  Dim Listds as New DataSet
  Dim Listcnn as OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ListConnectionString)
  Dim ListAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

  Dim Parameterds As New DataSet
  Dim ParameterAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter 
  Dim ParameterSelectQuery As String = "..."
  Dim ParameterSelectCommand As New OleDbCommand(ParameterSelectQuery, Listcnn)
  ParameterAdapter.SelectCommand = ParameterSelectCommand
  ******** ParameterAdapter.Fill(Parameterds) ********

  Dim Parameter As String = Parameterds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

  Dim ListSelectQuery As String = "...WHERE Value = '" & Parameter & "';"

  Dim ListSelectCommand As New OleDbCommand(ListSelectQuery, Listcnn) 
  ListAdapter.SelectCommand = ListSelectCommand

  ListAdapter.Fill(Listds)
  Return Modelds

End Function
```

The code is returning on the line with ********, but should return on the return statement. I've also tried this with separate functions, but it still does the same thing.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually getting an exception.

Comment: That is possible, although I've stepped through and none were thrown. The form loads as normal, although no breakpoints past that point are ever hit. It does make sense that it could be an exception.

Comment: That was it. I hadn't implemented any error handling yet (Try, Catch), so it didn't show up, but it is an error in the SELECT query. Most likely because someone thought it would be a good idea to put spaces in the table name. :P Thanks!